# SQL- gettings all records from a table that share a value in two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

The title is a bit vague, so here goes.

I have a table: `tag_tasks`

It is a join table with two columns of importance: `tag_id` and `task_id`

I'd like to get a count of the number of tasks that have both tags.

For example: I have a `task(id = 12)` and a `tag(id = 24` and another `tag(id = 30)`

in tag_tasks I would have these records:

```
tag_id  task_id
24      12
30      12
```

Let's say there are also some records in there to make it realistic:

```
tag_id  task_id
24      12
30      12
36      43
24      45
56      98
24      115
30      115
```

I want to return a record ONLY if the task_id has both my target tags associated with it. In this case, it would be only the first two rows (task_id = 12) and the last two rows (task_id = 115) and then get a total count (in this case my end goal would be to return the number four).

**EDIT- RESULT SETS**

```
tag_id  task_id
    24      12
    30      12
    24      115
    30      115
```

but Finally I'd like to end up with something like this (a sum of the above results):

```
task_count_for_both_tags_combined
4
```

This is a bit confusing for me to think about, so please let me know if I can clarify my question.

Thank you.

**EDIT - MY RESULTS SO FAR**
This piece of code gets me close, but I need to add the resulting numbers - *note that this is juts the current dataset, there could be any number of rows where I group by task_id*

```
SELECT COUNT( task_id ) AS task_count, tag_id
FROM  `tag_tasks` 
WHERE tag_id
IN ( 15, 11 ) 
GROUP BY task_id
HAVING task_count >1
```

This leaves me with this result, which I would need the sum of:

```
task_count  task_id 
2           34
2           45
```

**Edit - SQLFIDDLE EXAMPLE**
I just learned this existed, so here is an incorrect fiddle answer from one of the posters with a slightly larger data set. This sql ends up selecting records with a different tag than the ones I'd like (31 and 32 instead of JUST 24 and 30).

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/116f9/1/0

Comment: please display final result in your question .

Comment: This seems so close - I feel like you're almost there!?!?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName a
WHERE exists( 
    select 1 
    from tableName b 
    where a.task_id = b.task_id
    and tag_id = 24)
AND exists( 
    select 1 
    from tableName b 
    where a.task_id = b.task_id
    and tag_id = 30)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03ac9/2/0)

Change `SELECT *` to `SELECT COUNT(*)` if you want the number of records returned instead of the actual records. Or, if you just want the number of task_ids meeting this criteria, use `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT task_id)`

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work for the count part:

```
select 2*count(task_id) where task_id in (select task_id where tag_id=24) and task_id in (select task_id where tag_id=30)
```

Basically, if the task has both tags add it to the count and double it at the end.  The where clause could be recycled for a general select to get the other data.

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(distinct(t1.task_id))-1 
from tag_tasks t1, tag_tasks t2 
where t1.task_id = t2.task_id 
    and t1.tag_id = t2.tag_id
```

as in [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5c4e/3). Any questions, leave a comment.

Comment: That leaves me with 5, when there are only 4 records that share both tag_ids

Answer (score 1):

OK, what I think you want is to show Task records that are related by this xref table to all of the Tags you're interested in. So, specifically, you want all Tasks that have a tag-task cross-reference record tying the task to both tag 24 and tag 30.

This is probably best accomplished with two inner joins, both between Task and Tag-Task.

```
SELECT t.taskId --or COUNT(*)
FROM Task t
INNER JOIN TagTasks tt1
   ON tt1.taskId = t.taskId
   AND tt1.tagId = 24
INNER JOIN TagTasks tt2
   ON tt2.taskId = t.taskId
   AND tt2.tagId = 30
```

Results:

```
12
115
```

... if you want your exact result set as defined in your question, modify the select and add a third join:

```
SELECT tt3.tagId, t.taskId
FROM Task t
INNER JOIN TagTasks tt1
   ON tt1.taskId = t.taskId
   AND tt1.tagId = 24
INNER JOIN TagTasks tt2
   ON tt2.taskId = t.taskId
   AND tt2.tagId = 30
INNER JOIN TagTasks tt3
   ON tt3.taskId = t.taskId
   AND (tt3.tagId = 24 OR tt3.tagId = 30)
```

Results:

```
tag_id  task_id
24      12
30      12
24      115
30      115
```

Joins are cheap, when they use indexed columns (like primary key fields), so this select should perform faster than an Exists or other subquery. Because all the joins are Inner joins, they all have to have match the filter and joining criteria in order for any result row for that combination to be produced. It shouldn't produce a Cartesian join either, as each clause will match one and only one tag ID, so you won't get duplicate results based on the first join matching tag 24 in one row and then tag 30 in the next.

However, this isn't an easy query to automate as a stored proc; you'll need a Join for each tag you want to search on, plus the Join that will provide the field for the select list, so it's nigh impossible to hard code a single query in this form that will do what you want without producing Cartesian joins etc. But, this query, with its iteratively repeated boilerplate parts, is relatively easily to generate in application code and send over the wire to the server (just don't inline anything the end user types in, as always).

Comment: I'm starting to think that grabbing more records than I need and simply doing the rest in ruby is looking like a might fine alternative, although for learning purposes I'd love to see how someone would solve this in SQL, as well as learn about when something stops being worth doing in SQL and becomes more efficient to do in procedural code.

Comment: Well, the filtering, sorting, grouping etc is usually best left to the database. The more data you ask for, the more you have to deal with in code, and your code is a couple decades behind the development effort inherent in the average DB engine (and hopefully running on a machine with a tenth the resources of your DB server) so whatever you can do in your code, the DB server can do faster. I would let the DB server do as much as you can tell it to do, and return as little data as you need.

Comment: Case in point, this query will only return unique task IDs that match your criteria, not joining them to the tag ID. That economizes somewhat on data bandwidth. All you would have to do to get your desired set is match each result with each of your tags as a unique row, and depending on how you'll use the data you don't even need that.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answers have given me a lot to think about. I'm going to try a few things out in my app and report back.

Answer (score 1):

Try Following query:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM tag_tasks AS A
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT TASK_ID , COUNT(*) AS CNT
FROM tag_tasks
WHERE TAG_ID = 24 OR TAG_ID = 30
GROUP BY TASK_ID
) AS B ON A.TASK_ID = B.TASK_ID
WHERE B.CNT = 2
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8369d/4)

I used join query. Join gives batter performance over EXIST and IN clause because Join query runs only one time at the time of execution but Query in EXIST and IN clause runs for each records in the table and it takes more time to produce result when we have lot of data in the table .

Answer (score 1):

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/116f9/3

Surely the 'record count' gives you the answer you're looking for!!

Comment: It does - but I end up with two records. Obviously a beginners question, but is there a way to simply end up with the total record count as opposed to the rows themselves?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your SQLfiddle in your edit works fine if you add the additional filter for the Tag_ID at the end, right?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM tableName a
WHERE exists( 
    select 1 
    from tableName b 
    where a.task_id = b.task_id
    and tag_id = 24)
AND exists( 
    select 1 
    from tableName b 
    where a.task_id = b.task_id
    and tag_id = 30)
AND (Tag_ID = 24 OR Tag_ID = 30) /* add this filter to exclude the IDs you don't want */
```